# R calculate nonlinear least squares with using specific bins

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I would really appreciate help with a problem I have in R that I am unable understand. I am trying to fit data using the nonlinear least squares algorithm, after creating a histogram of that data. I wish to exclude the first bin(s) of the histogram from the NLS calculation.

I have data with an exponential decay. I calculate a histogram of this data and fit a curve to it using NLS no problem:

```
density=(0.4805447471,0.3025291829,0.1128404669,0.0447470817,0.0243190661,0.0136186770,0.0058365759,0.0077821012,0.0048638132,0.0009727626,0.0009727626,0.0000000000,0.0000000000,0.0009727626)
breaks=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)

model=nls(density~a*exp(-b*breaks),start=list(a=y0,b=k))
```

But, owing to the nature of the data collection method, the first bin(s) of the histogram is possibly undersampled. Therefore I would like to calculate my nonlinear least squares model ignoring the first bin(s). To do this, I make new x/y variables without the first bin:

```
new_density=density[-1]
new_breaks=breaks[-1]
```

Now when running NLS as above, I get this error:

> 1: In lhs - rhs :
>         longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>       2: In .swts * (lhs - rhs) :
>         longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>       3: In .swts * attr(rhs, "gradient") :
>         longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>       Execution halted

I understand that new_density and new_breaks do indeed have different lengths (13 and 14 respectively), but this is the same for the original density and breaks (14 and 15 respectively) which do not cause this error.

As far as I can see density, breaks, new_density, and new_breaks are all just numeric vectors. Making density/breaks the same length introduces this error:

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>         Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
>       Calls: nls ...  -> assign -> assign -> getRHS -> numericDeriv
>       Execution halted

I can remove, say the second bin, and perform fitting with no problem.

Can anyone shed light on why NLS would require the first bin of my data for its calculations, and how I may go about performing the calcultion ignoring the first bin?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Alex

Comment: Hey there and welcome to SO. The message `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` is a warning, not an error, and you get that warning regardless of whether you exclude the first values of each vector or not. (As you correctly noted the lengths of the two vectors are different in both cases.) Please check that the code you pasted in your example is the same as what you ran yourself. I'm not sure if I am running the same code you ran.

Comment: As far as I can tell (given your values and breaks), _all_ of your values are in the first bin, i.e. between o and 1. Also, the result of breaks[-1] will be omitting the zero value.

Comment: Also the code creating `density` and `breaks` throws an error. (For a fairly obvious reason, once you know there's an error.)

Comment: Hey both, thanks for the welcome and thank you very much for helping me get going with R. I think I shot myself in the foot by trying to condense my code to make it easier to look at. `density` and `breaks` are the results from plotting my data using the hist() function. I now fully understand the problem and how to interpret R's messages - the error I get is in fact `Error in nls(prob ~ a * exp(-b * bins), start = list(a = y0, b = k)) : singular gradient`. Which appears only on removing the first bin, and is dealt with by giving better inital guesses for y0 and k. Thanks for helping me out!